# My discord bot is unable to mention a role

Tags: discord.py

The code segment for the mention:

```
hrole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,name="Heist")
await ctx.send(hrole.mention)
```

I've tried switching to <@&id> type mentions as well, but no matter how I change it it doesn't ping

what it does is send a @Heist which doesn't actually ping anyone

The bot has administrator permissions by the way

Comment: what’s the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the bot to ping the role cby changing the code to this:

```
    allowed_mentions = discord.AllowedMentions(roles = True)
    hrole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,name="Heist")
    await ctx.send(hrole.mention, allowed_mentions=allowed_mentions)
```

for some reason the allowed reactions were turned off in the cog, this can fix it